# Iterating over values that inside multiple lists which is part of a dictionary

Tags: python, python-2.7, dictionary, iteration, key-value

My dictionary is like this

```py
proj_d = {
    'key_A:': [u'1361808,1359404,1357929'],
    'key_B:': [u'1361808,1359404,1357929'],
    'Key_C:': [u'1361808,1359404,1357929'],
    'Key_D:': [u'1361808,1359404,1357929']
}
```

This is the return format from a method.

The area I'm blocked is at iterating the items inside each list, since the list cannot be accessed using index values and key strings.

Need assistance in unpacking items inside the lists.

I'm using python 2.7(If needed I can switch to python 3.7)

Comment: Have a look at some of the methods like `keys()`, and `items()` available on [`dict`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#dict).

Comment: I tried them including `iteritems()` and `iterkeys()`. Still have trouble unpacking the values

Comment: As @gold_cy says below, your lists of with a single string as a value.

Answer (score 0):

The items in your lists are strings which is why you need to use `split` to break them apart first. Also you mention you can switch to Python3.7, I would recommend doing so as Python2.7 has reached end of life way back in January.

```
for k, v in proj_d.items():
    print(f"Currently inside key {k}")
    for val in v[0].split(','):
        print(f"Currently at value {val}")

Currently inside key key_A:
Currently at value 1361808
Currently at value 1359404
Currently at value 1357929
Currently inside key key_B:
Currently at value 1361808
Currently at value 1359404
Currently at value 1357929
Currently inside key Key_C:
Currently at value 1361808
Currently at value 1359404
Currently at value 1357929
Currently inside key Key_D:
Currently at value 1361808
Currently at value 1359404
Currently at value 1357929
```

To make it more generic where your lists can hold more than one string change it to the following.

```
from itertools import chain

for k, v in proj_d.items():
    print(f"Currently inside key {k}")
    vals = (item.split(',') for item in v)
    for val in chain.from_iterable(vals):
        print(f"Currently at value {val}")
```